# Set value of dynamically built select option and apply change in outerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

In the following code, the selected option is not being displayed ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwdb7wty/)):

```
var options = ["option1", "option2", "option3"]
var $select = $("<select></select>");

$.each(options, function(index, value) {
   var $option = $("<option></option>", {
     "text": value,
     "value": value
   });
   $select.append($option);
});
$select.val("option3");
$('#dropdown').append($select.prop("outerHTML")); // 'dropdown' is an id of a div
```

Now, it would have worked if I would've do: `append($select)`, but I need to use the `outerHTML`. How can I set the value of the select element so that it is affected in the `outerHTML`?

Comment: You want to display the value of selected option on outerHTML of `$select`? Also is there any reason you can't use `append` and have to use `outerHTML`

Comment: Yes - and that the selected option will be rendered, i.e.,displayed to the user. In the above code, `"option3"` should be displayed as selected. And yes, there is a reason I can't use `append($select)`, and the reason is that in my actual code I don't even have a `div` element to append to, it's all dynamically built. However, for the purpose of asking this question it was more convenient for me to add a `div` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [**updated fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/pwdb7wty/3/)

The problem is that after you selected the value for dropdown as:

```
$select.val("option3");
```

You need to put this line of code, **which adds "selected" attribute to the selected option**:

```
$select.find("option:selected").attr('selected', true);
```

Here is the complete code from fiddle:

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    BuildDropdown();
});

function BuildDropdown()
{
   var options = ["option1", "option2", "option3"]
   var $select = $("<select></select>");

   $.each(options, function(index, value) {
      var $option = $("<option></option>", {
        "text": value,
        "value": value,
        //"id": value
      });
      $select.append($option);
    });
    $select.val("option3");
    $select.find("option:selected").attr('selected', true);//adds "selected" attribute to the selected option
    $('#dropdown').append($select.prop("outerHTML"));

    console.log($select.prop("outerHTML"));// will output: <select><option value="option1">option1</option><option value="option2">option2</option><option value="option3" selected="selected">option3</option></select>
}
```

Comment: I don't think you read to the end of my question - I said I know I can use `append($select)` but need to use `"outerHTML"`.

Comment: What do you mean by "need to use outerHTML" ? What do you need to do exactly?

Comment: I need that in the end of the function, `outerHTML` will contain that dom data that indicates which option is selected.

Comment: If you do console.log($select.prop("outerHTML"))) then it will output: <select><option value="option1">option1</option><option value="option2">option2</option><option value="option3">option3</option></select>

So I still can't get on "I need that in the end of the function".

Comment: I guess that the attribute `selected="selected"` should somehow be inserted into the required element.

Comment: Yes, but it isn't like that way. You won't get the selected="selected" in such a way. So after your function completes, if you want to know which option is currently selected then you can see that from my updated answer

Comment: Again, I know I can't get it that way, that's why I asked the question. Anyway, I don't mind what *way* to use - as long as at the end of the function, `outerHTML` will have this attribute. To clarify: The two ending lines of my function are probably wrong, and I want to know how to fix it. So I'm afraid your updated answer still doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I have again updated my answer, and I think that I have finally achieved what you wanted :).

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, an UP on my answer would also be really appreciated :). An UP for your question too